# jstl set tag with url tag

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I have an form which will used to add/update the user entity, since the server support the REST, so I need to decide the form action for adding or updating:

This is what I have done:

```
<c:set var="form_submit" value="<c:url value='/user'/>"/>
<c:if test="${user.id}>0">
    <c:set var="form_submit" value="<c:url value='/user/${user.id}'/>"/>
</c:if>
```

Then in the form:

```
<form  action="${form_submit}" method="post" ....
```

However I got this:

```
<form  action="<c:url value='/user'/>" method="post" ....
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare a variable for url:

```
 <c:url value='/user' var='userUrl'/>
```

then use it in form:

```
 <form  action="${userUrl}" method="post" ....
```